# How to calculate sale or purchase of stock in the cash flow statement from a balance sheet and an income statement?

Tags: untagged

with a balance sheet and an income statement as sources, how can I calculate the line « sale (or purchase) of stock » of a cash flow statement ?

Comment: I'm not sure I see how there are connected. Cash flow is about the company's operating income and expense. Stock sale and purchase is about ownership and any dividends the company is expected to declare. One can not be computed from the other